# Data e Hora em JAVA com MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, data

Estou trabalhando com MySQL x JAVA

Qual seria a melhor maneira de trabalhar com datas e horas? Separados (Date, Time), juntos (Datetime, timestamp)?

E em JAVA, considerando que estou usando uma API rest json e uma classe PARCELABLE para gravar em uma base SQLite e então manipular os dados.

E viabilizando futuras alterações, como fuso horário, GMT, outras regiões.

Comment: É android, Java SE, Java EE ou outra coisa?

Comment: É MySQL, tal como no título, ou é SQLite, tal como no texto da pergunta?

Comment: Android Studio (Editado)

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de trabalhar com datas e horas depende muito de como estas informações serão usadas e para que servem.

Por exemplo, se você vai gravar a data de nascimento em um cadastro simples de usuário, talvez só precise da data (dia, mês e ano), e nem precise se preocupar com as horas. Mas se for um sistema de maternidade, ou qualquer outro que precise do dia e horário exatos do nascimento, aí será necessário gravar a data e a hora, e provavelmente o local (ou o próprio timezone).

Se você precisa gravar o instante exato em que algo aconteceu, então o timestamp (ou a data e hora em UTC) seriam o mais indicado. As datas e horas locais podem sofrer alterações, como o horário de verão, que faz com que horas sejam puladas ou repetidas. Já o instante em UTC/timestamp representam um ponto específico na linha do tempo e não há ambiguidade, nem problemas com horário de verão (ou qualquer outra alteração no fuso horário).

Por exemplo, quando o horário de verão acaba no Brasil: à meia-noite, os relógios são atrasados em uma hora, de volta para 23h. Se você tem esta data com o horário igual a 23h, como saber se ele se refere ao momento antes ou depois que acabou o horário de verão? Você pode usar UTC ou o timestamp correspondente, ou então o offset (a diferença com relação a UTC - no caso do horário de Brasília, são 3 horas atrás de UTC no horário normal (`-03:00`) e 2 horas atrás de UTC no horário de verão (`-02:00`)). Mas para estes casos, acho que o melhor é gravar em UTC, e aí você converte para outros timezones, conforme a necessidade (mostrar para o usuário, por exemplo).

---

Apesar de existir uma recomendação geral de "sempre usar UTC", existe um caso em que não é o mais recomendado: quando você quer gravar eventos futuros.

Exemplo: **vamos supor que estamos em 2016**, e um usuário cadastrou um evento para 31 de outubro de 2018, às 10h, horário de Brasília.

Em 2016, a regra do horário de verão dizia que ele começa no terceiro domingo de outubro. Ou seja, em 30 de outubro de 2018, já seria horário de verão, e o offset usado (a diferença com relação a UTC) é de menos duas horas (`-02:00`).

Portanto, a data/hora e offset do evento futuro seria `2018-10-31T10:00-02:00`, o que em UTC corresponde a `2018-10-31T12:00Z` (o "Z" no final significa que a data/hora está em UTC, de acordo com o [formato definido pela norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))). Então você grava este valor no banco.

Até aí tudo bem. Só que o horário de verão é definido pelo governo, e ele pode mudar de ideia a qualquer momento. E no caso, mudou mesmo: a regra do Horário Brasileiro de Verão foi mudada por um [decreto publicado em dezembro de 2017](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2017/decreto/D9242.htm). Segundo a nova regra, a partir de 2018 o início do horário de verão é no primeiro domingo de novembro.

Portanto, pelas novas regras, 30 de outubro de 2018 não está mais em horário de verão, o que significa que neste dia o horário de Brasília ainda está 3 horas atrás de UTC. E convertendo o valor em UTC que havia sido gravado no banco (`2018-10-31T12:00Z`) para o offset `-03:00`, o resultado é `2018-10-31T09:00-03:00` (9 da manhã, uma hora antes do que foi cadastrado pelo usuário).

Para este caso específico, o melhor é gravar a data e hora **sem** offset, e guardar o nome do timezone em um campo separado. No caso, você poderia usar `America/Sao_Paulo`, que é o identificador da [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (o banco de dados de informações de timezones que o Java usa) para o horário de Brasília: a IANA costuma usar o nome da cidade mais populosa de cada região que possui as mesmas regras para definir seus horários locais.

Caso esse não seja o timezone dos seus usuários, você pode verificar a lista de todos os disponíveis. No Java, você pode usar `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` (Java >= 8) ou `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` (Java <= 7) para saber quais os IDs disponíveis.

Também é possível saber os timezones usados por determinado país no repositório da IANA. Os timezones do Brasil, por exemplo, [estão aqui](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone1970.tab#L85).

Os identificadores da IANA são a forma recomendada, pois eles possuem todo o histórico de offsets de cada região do planeta, incluindo as datas em que o horário de verão começa e termina, e quais os offsets antes e depois.

---

A IANA sempre lança atualizações frequentes do seu banco de dados, pois os timezones [mudam o tempo todo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/). Para atualizar as informações na JVM, você pode usar o [TZ Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html), que atualiza estes dados sem precisar mudar a versão do Java.

Ou você pode acompanhar [neste link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) qual a versão do banco da IANA cada versão do Java possui. A atualização do horário de verão brasileiro, por exemplo, já está nas versões  10, 8u172, 7u181 e 6u191.

---

Falando especificamente no seu caso, o SQLite não possui tipos específicos de data, gravando tudo em strings, [conforme explica a documentação](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Já o MySQL possui [tipos específicos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) que você pode usar conforme o que você precisar (somente a data, data e hora, timestamp, etc).

No Java 8 foram criadas classes específicas para estes casos também, no pacote `java.time`. Um `LocalDate` representa somente uma data (dia, mês e ano, sem qualquer interferência de timezones ou horário de verão), `LocalDateTime` (data e hora sem timezone), `LocalTime` (somente o horário), `OffsetDateTime` (data, hora e offset fixo, sem horário de verão) e `ZonedDateTime` (data, hora e timezone, com regras de horário de verão, etc).

A partir do JDBC 4.2 é possível usar as classes do `java.time`, desde que o driver do banco também seja compatível. Caso contrário, você terá que usar a API antiga (`java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` e `java.sql.Timestamp`).